# Selenium doesn't use FF profile with trusted SSL certificate

Tags: java, selenium

I created Selenium profile in FF, accepted SSL certificate in it. When I launch Selenium tests, it creates customProfileDir in /tmp folder and tries to use CyberVillainCA cert instead of one I need. I can accept this certificate once per test and should re-accept it every time I launch my tests.

I use the following arg line:

```
-firefoxProfileTemplate ${PATH_TO_FIREFOX_PROFILE} -trustAllSSLCertificates
```

But it seems to me, that it doesn't work.

How it can be fixed?

Addition info:

OS: Linux

Firefox: 12.0

Selenium IDE: 1.8.0

Selenium server: 2.21.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you accepted the certificate in a profile and is using that profile to run the test -trustAllSSLCertificates parameter is not required.

> Try removing -trustAllSSLCertificates and see if it works.

I have seen that when you give -trustAllSSLCertificates and the firefox profile template it doesn't work. But if you remove the files **cert8.db and cert_override.txt (which gets created when you accept the SSL certificate)** from your profile folder -trustAllSSLCertificates works fine.

Comment: By the way, cert_override.txt isn't created at all.

Comment: You can try it both ways. Remove -firefoxProfileTemplate parameter and use -trustAllSSLCertificates alone. Just make sure you keep only one.

Comment: Without -firefoxProfileTemplate it works... from time to time and uses CyberVillain certificate instead of mine :(
Continue investigate this problem, but I caught the idea.

Comment: Thank you so much A.J (thats my initial btw). It worked for me. The evil -trustAllSSLCertificates was the culprit all this while