# How to handle the selenium webdriver scripts due to security alerts in all browser?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Can anyone give the solution how i will handle the scripts in selenium web driver, however its gives the security alerts(Trusted certificates) issue so unable to record it. Please help me how can we came over this problem.

Comment: You need to give more information if you want a constructive response. What browser are you using (including version number) and which version of Selenium are you using? You suggest Selenium WebDriver but also mention recording; what code is failing?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430162/selenium-doesnt-use-ff-profile-with-trusted-ssl-certificate/10434217#10434217

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the id for the "Continue to Webpage" link is 'overridelink' (which it generally is)...

Try this:

```
driver.navigate().to("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");
```